# Two angular applications inside jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a jhipster application with its admin application located under `src/main/webapp/app`.

I need to incorporate another client application which is built in angular 5 (based on templates like the ones you can download from envato or similar.

I am not able to import the entire application under the jhipster angular as this is angular 5 and jhipster is using angular4.

Beside this, I feel that having two completely separated application would be best for maintenance and development.

Does anyone have an idea on how to configure jhipster to have two applications under `/webapp`?

Comment: I have done it with a second app generated by angular cli, I just copied the built bundled app under a sub folder of webapp and excluded it from JHipster webpack configuration.

Comment: care to elaborate in an answer that I can accept? are you able to use ng-cli in the subfolder? how did you exclude it from webpack? what about the routing?